# Pub/Sub paradigm: Can I know if subscribers are alive?

Tags: java, jms, messaging, activemq-classic

I am using JMS (ActiveMQ) between a Topic Publisher and a variable number of Topic Subscribers.

I would have to check if, at a given moment in time, some of the subscribers are "offline" (disconnected, shutdown, unable to communicate, etc...).
Is there a way that JMS allows the publisher to know which subscribers are "registered"?

Right now, I have it implemented so that subscribers send an "alive" message on a specific Queue (acting as producers) and the publisher receives them (acting as a consumer): if it is detected that any of the subscribers didn't "ping" for X seconds (threshold), it is assumed to be offline.
It works, but I was curious to know if I reinvented the wheel...

I know that this feature is not completely related to Messaging or Pub/Sub paradigm and I also know that Pub/Sub is specifically designed so that the publisher doesn't have to worry about who/where/when its messages will be consumed....but I was wondering that, if it DID want to know, maybe there was a way.
After all, it doesn't seem like a particularly uncommon usecase....

Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe using durable subscriptions as shown in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937262/how-to-find-out-all-subscribers-to-a-jms-topic-have-replied

Comment: @Alfabravo The solution shown in that thread is specific for HornetQ. Also DurableSubscriptions are not really about what I want to check, are they?? All they do is to keep messages in memory so that they can be delivered to "unreacheable" subscribers....this doesn't expose that list of subscribers to my program.

Comment: Nope, that setting is not bound to HornetQ. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncgd/index.html Aaaand well, maybe with the adequate workaround, it might help you http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncfx/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to tell your publisher the information about the subscribers directly.

what you should do is actually use [AMQ advisory messages](http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html) to keep track of the statuses of your subscribers. Read the article - it provides all the information you need.

Answer (score 2):

JMS explicitly decouples publishers from subscribers.  The whole point was supposed to be that the two did not need to know or care about the state of the other.  Therefore *JMS* has no facility to do what you require.  On the other hand, providers will have vendor-specific administration APIs and, as Paul notes, the AMQ advisory messages are what you want with Active MQ. Because these are vendor-specific it will not be portable to any other provider though and will not be JMS compliant.  Not the fault of AMQ, just that it's not part of the JMS spec.